# headerview from previous view takes up space in UISearchController search results

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a simple tableView, DailyAttendanceController, with a searchbar. Searchbar was added in its viewDidLoad. [View TableView here.](http://s23.postimg.org/wkh7cte63/firsttable.png)

```
import UIKit

class OldCellsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let data = ["A", "B", "C"]
    var searchController:UISearchController!
    let resultsController = SearchResultsUpdater()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        resultsController.data = data

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)

        let searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar
        searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Short", "Long"]
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search for a student"
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar

        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = resultsController
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let info = data[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = info
        return cell
    }

}
```

I then created another class, SearchResultsController, to handle the search. Searching works fine, but space is allocated for DailyAttendanceController's header. [View SearchResultsController here](http://s17.postimg.org/wuh6nunzj/oie_filh_DSy8_GFLg.png)

How do I remove this?

Code for my SearchResultsController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class SearchResultsController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

var data:[String] = []
var filteredData:[String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredData.count
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    filteredData.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text

    for info in data {
        if (info.uppercaseString.rangeOfString(searchString.uppercaseString) != nil) {
            filteredData.append(info)
        }
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

}
```

Comment: How is the layout of the tableView set in your view? Do you use storyboard with auto layout?

Comment: @JacobsonTalom no autolayout. It's a simple tableviewcontroller that I dragged from right-hand utilities pane

Comment: try setting some constraints (especially the top), might just fix it.

Comment: the tableview inside the tableviewcontroller won't let me set any constraints though. when I ctrl+click in any direction it only shows 'delegate' and 'datasource' in the popover

Comment: ah sorry, I thought you wrote you were using a `UIVIewController`.

Comment: I recreated a sample with your code, but I don't have any empty spaces between the table and the searchController. Can you show some code of your SearchResultsController as well?

Comment: I've added the complete code for both views. thanks for helping checking this out.